# AQL for the smallest common ancestor for n nodes

Tags: graph, arangodb

I am relatively new to arango graph and I am trying to find a solution for my graph problem.
My graph looks like this:

[image]

I have multiple start nodes and all of them SHOULD connect in an end node which is unknown to me.
I am searching for an AQL to find these connecting end node in my graph.
Is it possible with arango to find these node? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
LET startingNodes = ['nid1', 'nid2', ...] //or @nids

LET vArrs = (
  FOR snode in startingNodes
  RETURN (
    FOR v, e, p in 0..@maxDepth
    OUTBOUND snode
    GRAPH @graphName //or list of edge collections
    OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: 'path'}
    RETURN {id: v._id, dist: length(p.vertices)}
  )
)

LET vidArrs = (
  FOR vArr in vArrs
  RETURN (
   FOR v in vArr RETURN v.id
  ) 
)

LET vCommon = APPLY('INTERSECTION', vidArrs)

FOR v in FLATTEN(vArrs)
  FILTER v.id in vCommon
  SORT v.dist ASC
  LIMIT 1
RETURN v.id
```

Comment: I haven't run this on a real graph, since I don't have a reasonably sized sample graph with the structure you described.